# isomorphism of power set and cartesian product

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How to prove that the ring of cartesian product $\mathbb Z_{2}^n$  under addition and multiplication is isomorphic to $P(N)$, where $P(N)$ is the ring of power set of a set with $n$ elements where the multiplication operation is $AB=A\cup B$ and the addition operation is $A+B=AΔB$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Think about a concrete example, say $N = \{x, y, z\}$ with $n = 3$.

If $A = \{x, y\}$ and $B = \{y, z\}$, then we can associate them with the tuples $\vec a = (1, 1, 0)$ and $\vec b = (0, 1, 1)$. Then $A \cap B = \{y\}$ (corresponding to $(0, 1, 0)$) and $A ~\Delta~ B = \{x, z\}$ (corresponding to $(1, 0, 1)$).